# Failed to customize Swagger UI in my project with Swashbuckle

Tags: swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I followed the instruction and added two files as "Embedded Resources" in my Swagger folder:

```
APIDemo
  |
  |------ Swagger
           |
           |----index.html
           |----style.css
```

My SwaggerConfig.cs:

```
 .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
   {
    c.InjectStylesheet(thisAssembly, "APIDemo.Swagger.style.css");
    c.CustomAsset("index", thisAssembly, "APIDemo.Swagger.index.html");
```

But I got the following error messages when I run the project:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:53670/swagger/ui/lib/underscore-min-js
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:53670/swagger/ui/lib/handlebars-2-0-0-js
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:53670/swagger/ui/lib/underscore-min-js
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) backbone-min-js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined swagger-ui-js:9
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined http://localhost:53670/swagger/ui/lib/highlight-7-3-pack-js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) index:54
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: SwaggerUi is not defined

What could be the reason? Thanks.

Comment: Fixed the problem by using index.html in master branch. Then comes a new question. How to refer to other asset files, i.e., image files in my index.html?

Comment: You can just add files in your `Content` folder, and then point to it from your embedded `index.html` file.